# understanding training layers and filters term used in tensorflow mnist tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, convolution

I've been working on [this example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers) from tensorflow.org to understand the layers.

one question I came through while studying convolution layer is that I can't seem to find out how the number of filters serve the purpose in convolution layer. see for example below line of code uses 32 filters.

```
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=input_layer,
    filters=32,
    kernel_size=[5, 5],
    padding="same",
    activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

I can see that it produces 32 channel tensor as output but I can't figure out what's the 32 filters exactly doing in model. is it that that model had tried 32 random iterations to come up with 32 channel tensor of different representation of input? I don't think so. The only thing I can imagine is that its the training iterations done 32 times or something like that but not sure of it. looking at tensorboard graph of convolution layer does not make it clear about the flow of filters.

[image]

While taking snap I came though 32 number of weights and biases though, so I think that's that. is it the 32 weights and biases? In which case can anyone through more light one underlying computation scene which I think I can't though tensorboard.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you give http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/ a reading to learn in depth about what various components in a CNN basically do.
Quoting directly from there :-

> Intuitively, the network will learn filters that activate when they see some type of visual feature such as an edge of some orientation or a blotch of some color on the first layer, or eventually entire honeycomb or wheel-like patterns on higher layers of the network.

Giving that a reading would definitely help.

Comment: Thanks Naman for the answer. At one point I'd came across above link but never studied that one deeply but I will and I know it will help. But some of my doubts are about how the convolution layer coded in tensorflow internally say for e.g in graph image in question if you see there is two tiny graph within convolution layer graph, one of which is conv2D and the other is relu so as usual relu would be doing what its supposed too than what is conv2d there for? in tensor graph there is some info about what it takes as input and output but not clear enough. I think all its doing is training